# Macbook Pro 13 Retina battery drain using Chrome browser

Tags: battery, macbook-pro, google-chrome

I'm planning on purchasing a Macbook Pro Retina 8GB/256GB to replace a 2009 Macbook Pro. I'm a long time Mac user but my hesitation is whether the Chrome browser battery drain issue in Mavericks has been addressed either by Google or Apple. I use both Safari and Chrome in my workflow, each have their benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not consume more energy than the other browsers in this test.

I just ran a comparison.

The set up was to have same amount of demand.

Three tabs were open, one tab streaming online video in both, Chrome and Firefox (I do not use Safari).

In Energy consumption profile below, Chrome was equal to Firefox.

Of course the Energy consumption is very much dependent on the particular web site.

[image: energy]

Answer (score 0):

Safari actually uses less energy than crime or Firefox but it honestly depends on the website open and number of tabs